# Convert Pandas DataFrames with different columns into an iterable and reform as one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert the three DataFrames `a,b,c` below into one DF with columns `A,B,C,D`?

I specifically want to gather the multiple DataFrames into one iterable (dict/list of dicts) before reconstituting them as one DF instead of appending or concatenating them.

My attempt:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,8,9],'B':[10,11,12]})
c=pd.DataFrame({'B':[13,14,15],'C':[16,17,18],'D':[19,20,21]})

list_of_dicts=[] #can be list of lists/dicts 

for i in [a, b, c]:
    x=i.to_dict('split')
    list_of_dicts.append(x)

pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_of_dicts)
```

#Solved below. Credit to Eric Truett.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

a=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,8,9],'B':[10,11,12]})
c=pd.DataFrame({'B':[13,14,15],'C':[16,17,18]})

list_of_dicts=[]

for i in [a, b, c]:
    x=i.to_dict('records')
    list_of_dicts.append(x)

pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_dicts)))
```

Comment: The ```to_dict``` method of a dataframe will create a list of dicts if you use the ```records``` parameter. Then you would just need to add the three converted dataframes together to make one list, or you could use itertools.chain.from_iterable.

Comment: You nailed it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To create a single dataframe from these three, you can use the [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) function in pandas:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,8,9],'B':[10,11,12]})
c=pd.DataFrame({'B':[13,14,15],'C':[16,17,18],'D':[19,20,21]})

d = pd.concat([a, b, c])
print(d)
```

will give you:

```
     A   B     C     D
0  1.0   4   NaN   NaN
1  2.0   5   NaN   NaN
2  3.0   6   NaN   NaN
0  7.0  10   NaN   NaN
1  8.0  11   NaN   NaN
2  9.0  12   NaN   NaN
0  NaN  13  16.0  19.0
1  NaN  14  17.0  20.0
2  NaN  15  18.0  21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `append` function to adding up multiple `DataFrame` objects. In the code below I initialize a variable `s` that will be used to combine all `a, b, c` `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

a=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,8,9],'B':[10,11,12]})
c=pd.DataFrame({'B':[13,14,15],'C':[16,17,18],'D':[19,20,21]})

list_of_dicts=[] #can be list of lists/dicts 

s = pd.DataFrame()
for i in [a, b, c]:
    s = s.append(i)

print(s)
```

Printing `s` would give the following output

```
     A   B     C     D
0  1.0   4   NaN   NaN
1  2.0   5   NaN   NaN
2  3.0   6   NaN   NaN
0  7.0  10   NaN   NaN
1  8.0  11   NaN   NaN
2  9.0  12   NaN   NaN
0  NaN  13  16.0  19.0
1  NaN  14  17.0  20.0
2  NaN  15  18.0  21.0
```